# At runtime how does one determine which mono version is being used?

Tags: c#, mono

On a system multiple mono runtime versions may exist.
For example

```
/usr/bin/mono
/usr/local/bin/mono
```

When creating a new managed process from a C# application it can be useful to be explicit about which mono version you want to run it with. (The mono in the path may not be the mono being used to run the current process)

Using the Process class to get the current process name returns the assembly that mono is running not mono itself.

What is the best way to determine which mono runtime is currently being used?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the process Id and `/proc` can be used to find the mono executable.

```
string monopath = String.Format("/proc/{0}/exe", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
```

monopath will be a symlink to the current executing mono runtime, and can be used to launch a new process:

```
Process.Start(monopath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    Type monoRuntimeType;
    MethodInfo getDisplayNameMethod;
    if ((monoRuntimeType = typeof(object).Assembly.GetType("Mono.Runtime")) != null &&
        (getDisplayNameMethod = monoRuntimeType.GetMethod("GetDisplayName",
          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.ExactBinding, null,
                  Type.EmptyTypes, null)) != null)

    Console.WriteLine("Mono " + (string)getDisplayNameMethod.Invoke(null, null));
```

Comment: I did look at Mono.Runtime. In my case its possible that there are multiple versions of mono installed all reporting the same runtime version. Also I think there is still a non trivial amount of work involved in getting the path location from the runtime version.